# Find the minimum possible order at a restaurant for a party of n people

Tags: optimization, algorithms

I want to find an efficient algorithm for determining the minimum possible order total for a party of n people at a restaurant, assuming that the items in the order are **unique**, and they will each order one item, or will share items based on the recommended number of people for those items. e.g. a party of 3 may order a steak and a pizza if the pizza is listed as a 2-person item on the menu. I have an algorithm that seems to work well when there are only single-person items on the menu, but the multi-person items throw a wrench into it. Here's what I have so far:

1. Order all items on the menu by increasing price.
2. For a party of n, take the sum of the prices of the first n items.

My next idea was that as I'm adding each item I would check to see if there is a multi-person item with a lower cost than the total so far. This improves the algorithm, but does not take into account the possibility of having multiple multi-person items.

Comment: What is the algorithm that seems to work well when there are only single-person items on the menu?

Comment: The one I described in 2 steps above. Order all items on the menu by increasing price and just take the sum of the prices of the first n items for a party of n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the number of people fed per item is not bounded above by a fixed constant, this is an NP-hard problem (i.e. it's almost guaranteed no fast solution exists). To see this, assume that you have $N$ people and you have a very expensive item that feeds $N$ people, and then you have a collection of very cheap multi-person items where the $i$th multi-person item serves $a_i$ people. Then ideally you want to find a subset of the cheap multi-person items such that $\sum_i a_i = N$ for the cheap multi-person items $i$ chosen in the subset. However that is the subset sum problem, which is NP-hard. So your problem is NP-hard. If you like, I can give you a pretty fast so-called dynamic programming solution assuming that the maximum number of people that an item can feed is bounded above by a fixed constant. Or you can read about it yourself, your problem is equivalent to the so-called "knapsack problem", e.g. you can read about on wikipedia and see the so-called dynamic programming solution.

Comment: This was more or less my suspicion, but I didn't know exactly how to show that it reduced to the subset sum problem. I'm somewhat familiar with NP-hard problems from college CX days, and I have come across the knapsack problem already while working on this project. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have soved the problem for all $n$ and a certain menu.
Now assume that a new $k$-person dish at cost $c$ is added to the menu.
Then the new optimum for $n$ persons is either the same as with the old menu, or it is the optimum for $n-k$ persons under the old menu plus $c$. This allows you to find the optimum for $N$ people and $M$ dishes in $O(NM)$ steps using $O(N) $ memory:

1. Set $f[0]\leftarrow 0$ and $f[i]\leftarrow+\infty$ for $1\le i\le N$
2. For $i=1,2\ldots, M$ do the following:
3. For $j=N,N-1,\ldots,k[i]$, assign $f[j]\leftarrow\min\{f[j],f[j-k[i]]+c[i]\}$, where $k[i]$ is the person-count and $c[i]$ is the cost of the $i$th item on the menu
4. Finally, $f[N]$ contains the answer.

Comment: I think I follow that, but this seems like a slightly different problem since you're just talking about adding one item to an existing menu where we already have answers for all n.